# NUnit Check if button was click

Tags: c#, nunit

I am learning how to do unit testing. I tried to search for how to do testing for a button click event but couldn't find an answer that I could understand. 
How can I check if `TextBlock_MouseDown` event was raised and followed by reponse from `PostMethod`, which must not be `null`. My issue is, I can't find a way or don't know how to check `TextBlock_MouseDown` event using `NUnit`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(){
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
        //Check return value from PostMethod
        string reponse = PostMethod("myurlhere");
    }

    public static String PostMethod(String val){
        //Code
    }
}




[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void PostMethod_IsAlive_returnHello()
    {
        //ARRANGE
        String url = "myurlhere";

        //ACT
        string response = MainWindow.PostMethod(url);

        //ASSERT
        Assert.AreEqual("\"Hello\"", response);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to test your `UI`, you should use a test library for UI-Testing. 
For example `FlaUI` (https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI).

`NUnit` is used to test your code behind. For example if you want to check if `PostMethod()` is returning a specific value.

---

If you only want to check the result of `PostMethod()`, outsource the `method` to another `class` and test it (**MainWindow will now use `OutsourcedClass.PostMethod()` in its code behind**).

## outsourced class

```
public class OutsourcedClass
{
    public string PostMethod(string url)
    {
        return url;
    }
}
```

## unit test

```
public class OutsourcedClassTest
{
    private OutsourcedClass _Instance;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _Instance = new OutsourcedClass();
    }

    [Test]
    public void PostMethodTest()
    {
        string url = "foo";
        Assert.AreEqual(url, _Instance.PostMethod(url));
    }
}
```

Comment: so its not possible to mock on click event in unit test? is that how it works? I am not testing my ui appearance. I am testing my backend.

Comment: `NUnit` only tests code behind, if you want to test your ui buttons you have to use `FlaUI`.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as answer 